# Not able to catch exception on DLL function call c#

Tags: c#, exception, dll, unhandled-exception

i'm developing an app that use external DLL to program drivers ( i have not DLL source code ).
In one of that DLL there is a function ( to read driver information) that, in a specific situation, throw an exception (NFCExceptionReadingFailure) that make my app crash.
Now i will show you the code to explain better:

```cs
ReadbackFileAvailableEventArgs Driver_INFO;

public void HandleReadbackCompletedEvent(ReadbackFileAvailableEventArgs DINFO)
{
    Driver_INFO = DINFO;
}

public Tuple<string, string, string, string, string> getDriverINFO()
{
    // Unsubscribe first
    ReadbackCompletedEvent -= HandleReadbackCompletedEvent;
    // then Subscribe 
    ReadbackCompletedEvent += HandleReadbackCompletedEvent;

    //With this line of code reading process is started on the DLL ( ReadFromDevice is a method of the dll)
    ProgrammingAPI.ApplicationConstants.ReturnCode ret = ReadFromDevice();

    //ret is Success if the process is started on the DLL
    if (ret == ApplicationConstants.ReturnCode.Success)
    {
        Console.Write("\nREADING...");
        // wait for programming or readback completion
        while (ProgrammingAPI.ProgrammingAPI.IsWorking())
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        Console.Write("\READING OK");
        .......
    }
}
```

I found that in a situation the reading process start correctly ( ret = Success ) but during the process the DLL throw an exception that make my app crash.

Placing the try catch on ReadFromDevice calling is useless ( this method is always executed correctly ). If i put the while inside a try catch the DLL exception still make my app crash.

There is a way to manage this situation and prevent app crash?

Comment: Have you tried catching the Unhandled Exception?  This can then give you some more insight as to the issue.

Comment: I have tried it using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionReaction); but this is not making my app stop crashing ( just give the possibility to log or make action before crash)

Comment: Yes, but it gives you the possibility to see what the exact error message is and then you can try to solve the problem base on this information, which is currently missing and makes it difficult to resolve.  If an external DLL is crashing, then most likely it is either a bug (and you need the exact error message to report to the devs), or you are not invoking it correctly, in which case the error message will help you find the error and fix it.

Comment: The DLL error is not a bug (error is raised when the user wrongly try to read uncompatible driver). I just want to prevent app crashing on that situation.

Comment: Then you need to catch it (maybe via unhandled exception handler) and simply suppress/ignore it.

Comment: Again, i'm not able to manage it to and avoid app crash. Try catch is not working and i'm there asking help to solve this problem.

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you more than "you need to find its origin and catch it or prevent the state that causes it or - if possible - both". That means: There may be more than one way to register for unhandled exceptions depending on your project type and you will need to investigate if there are "hidden dragons and crouching tigers" in your code that will bypass "normal" control flow and directly shoot your runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have published my app as a windows services and the unamanged exception doesn't make my app crash anymore. Now is seen as simple app error and i can use the software.